# Installing MySQL on Ubuntu with ruby on rails [ERROR]

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

getting an error when `bundle install` ing mysql below:
I have the workbench and server and i can connect to it, so this is NOT the issue.

```
Installing mysql (2.8.1) with native extensions /home/ahmet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:551:in `rescue in block in build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Instal ler::ExtensionBuildError)

        /home/ahmet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby extconf.rb  checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no checking for main() in -lm... yes checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no checking for main() in -lz... yes checking for mysql_query() in
-lmysqlclient... no checking for main() in -lsocket... no checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no checking for main() in -lnsl... yes checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no checking for main() in -lmygcc... no checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/home/ahmet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby
        --with-mysql-config
        --without-mysql-config
        --with-mysql-dir
        --without-mysql-dir
        --with-mysql-include
        --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
        --with-mysql-lib
        --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/lib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-mlib
        --without-mlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-zlib
        --without-zlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-socketlib
        --without-socketlib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-nsllib
        --without-nsllib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib
        --with-mygcclib
        --without-mygcclib
        --with-mysqlclientlib
        --without-mysqlclientlib


Gem files will remain installed in /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql-2.8.1 for inspection. Results logged to /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mysql-2.8.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:529:in `block in build_extensions'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:504:in `each'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:504:in `build_extensions'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:180:in `install'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.16/lib/bundler/source.rb:101:in `block in install'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.16/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:78:in `preserve_paths'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.16/lib/bundler/source.rb:91:in `install'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.16/lib/bundler/installer.rb:58:in `block (2 levels) in run'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.16/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:93:in `with_build_args'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.16/lib/bundler/installer.rb:57:in `block in run'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.16/lib/bundler/installer.rb:49:in `run'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.16/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in `install'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.16/lib/bundler/cli.rb:220:in `install'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.16/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.16/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.16/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:263:in `dispatch'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.16/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:386:in `start'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/bundler-1.0.16/bin/bundle:13:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle:19:in `load'
        from /home/ahmet/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using the ubuntu packages?

Comment: I have but im trying to convert from sqlite to mysql

Comment: I have the MySQL Client and Server from Software Centre

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Before the installation of mysql gem install following.

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev
```